# How to remove viruses

Tags: applications

I have a ZTE zmax and when the lock screen is on and I swipe it to open home screen it turns white and usually get a Google screen that says I have 5 mins to hit the button to remove the viruses. When I hit the button it goes to the play store on a virus app. If I ignore it I can just hit the home button and it goes to the home screen and everything else runs fine. I don't know how to get rid of it. It's a pain in the ass. Please help me.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of that "Google screen"? As of now, it's a bit unclear whether it's a browser pop-up, or ad from the malware. In general, just don't follow the instruction and you're safe.

Comment: Like Andrew, my guess is a bad app you've installed. I'd check the latest things added *before* this issue started, trying to remove those apps, and see if it kills the problem along.

Comment: I would agree, this is a malicious or trickery app and not a real virus... getting a virus on Android, although not impossible, is extremely rare. Start uninstalling apps in reverse order as best you can, and if all else fails, do a factory reset.

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/144170/i-installed-and-executed-this-app-which-is-a-virus-or-malware-now-what-to-do

Answer (score 0):

Android viruses are very rare to get hold of. Unless you have downloaded any app from any other source, other than the play store, you are not in the risk of any "virus" issues.

Android runs on top of a Linux kernel besides having multiple layer of protection the OS itself has it's on protection methods. [The image here will help you ease your mind.](http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--DCQ3tMp2--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/193dtvab4yyfmjpg.jpg)

Other than that your issues seems more of a malware in this particular case an Adware which bombards your device each time with a advert asking you to "fix your phone" the Google logo in these adverts are not of Google but a marketing gimmicks. The one sure way to test it out is to browse on your phone by turning off JavaScript in your chrome browser or by using other add-on in supported browsers like Firefox.